# Unbiased estimators for powers of binomial expected value (or p)

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, estimation, binomial-distribution

From this old paper (Glasser 1962, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1266576) I discovered that

$$\frac{x^{[i]}}{n^i}$$

is an unbiased estimator for $\lambda^i$, where $x = \sum_1^n x_j$ for a set of $n$ samples $x_j$ from the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, and where $x^{[i]}$ is defined as

$$x^{[i]} = \frac{x!}{(x-i)!}$$

In other words, given $x_j$, we can construct unbiased estimators for all (integer) powers of $\lambda$.

My question is this: is there an equivalent set of estimators for the binomial distribution? I.e. can we estimate all powers of, say, $pN$, where $p$ is the success probability and $N$ is the number of trials? I tested out the same formula numerically, since I figured that the Poisson distribution is just a limit of the binomial distribution so perhaps it would still work, but it does not. Numerically it seems that $x^{[i]}/n^i$ becomes an unbiased estimator of $(pN)^i$ only in the limit of large $N$.

But can this be fixed somehow? Is there a similar set of estimators that work in the general binomial case?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in Chapter 2 of ``Statistical Implications of Turing's Formula'' by Zhang, John Wiley and Sons (2017). The estimator is a bit convoluted in general form, but it is there. The estimator is given for a general multinomial distribution, binomial being a special case. The key thing to know is that an unbiased estimator of $p^{i}$ exists if $i\leq n$.

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I am not totally seeing it though, I guess it follows somehow from these unbiased estimators of "Simpson indices"?

Comment: Oh yeah, so if I set p_1 = p and p_2 = (1-p) then I guess unbiased estimators of the Simpson indices are somehow related to powers of p. I'm not totally sure how to invert that relationship but I will stare at it for a while and see if I figure it out...

Comment: @BenFarmer:   That is the spirit of Mathematics!!! :))